# Generate list and check if the values are increasing

Tags: prolog

Currently, I'm generating a list, in which each element has a value equal to the square of the preceding element plus the value of Z. After generating the list using generate_list, I want to check if it's an ordered list or not. I've implemented ordered and then in the console, I'm trying to do something like ordered(generate_list(A, B, Z,[])., which is returning always false, even when I'm sure that it must be true. I know that this approach is not good in Prolog but I don't know how to do it...

```
gen(0,0,_).
gen(N,F,Z) :- X is N-1,gen(X,A,Z),F is (A*A)+Z.

generate_list(A,B,Z,[]):- A>B.
generate_list(A,B,Z,[H|T]):-
    A =< B,
    gen(A,H,Z),
    AA is A + 1,
    generate_list(AA,B,Z,T).

ordered([]).
ordered([_]).
ordered([X,Y|Z]):-X=<Y,ordered([Y|Z]).
```

Comment: With what parameters do you generate a list here?

Comment: I used the same logic as for Fibonacci. So I'm using a start index(A), end index(B) and a value that will be added to the square of the preceding element( Z).

Answer (score 3):

I do not really see why you specify a function `gen/3` here. You can use an *accumulator*, and thus each time update the accumulator, like:

```
generate_list(N, Z, L) :-
    generate_list(N, Z, 0, L).

generate_list(0, _, _, []).
generate_list(N, Z, A, [A|T]) :-
    N > 0,
    B is A*A + Z,
    N1 is N-1,
    generate_list(N1, Z, B, T).
```

For example for `Z` is `1`, we get:

```
?- generate_list(5, 1, L).
L = [0, 1, 2, 5, 26] ;
false.
```

With the `ordered/1` predicate in your question, we see that this list is indeed ordered:

```
?- generate_list(5, 1, L), ordered(L).
L = [0, 1, 2, 5, 26] ;
false.
```

Whereas for `Z = -1`, it is not:

```
?- generate_list(5, -1, L).
L = [0, -1, 0, -1, 0] ;
false.

?- generate_list(5, -1, L), ordered(L).
false.
```

Comment: Yes, but as you can see the result is still false even if you do it as you said. Or is this just a typing mistake?

Comment: @IvanNickSim: no it produces a result `[0,1,2,5,26]`, but then Prolog looks for more results, and that search for more results does not yield any extra, hence `false`. The semicolon (`;`) in Prolog means "or". So the interpreter says: `L = [0, 1, 2, 5, 26]` or false, so only one result. In some cases the outcome is `X = 1; X = 3; false.` for example, then there are two solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. So actually my idea with the ordered thing is to return true if it's really ordered and false if it's not. Can you help for that?

Comment: @IvanNickSim: it does that, the backtracking node is in the `generate_list/3` part. You can however construct a predicate with `generate_list(N, Z, L), ordered(L)` as body that does not export `L` as a parameter, in which case it will print `true; false` for the first, and `false` for the latter. By using `once/1` you can let only one item show up.

Comment: what do you mean by using once/1?

Comment: Understanding where the choice point is coming from and if it can be avoided altogether is also important ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your `ordered/1` probably works as it is. But it leaves behind a choice point! You could use `once( sorted(L) )`.

"Ordered" is somewhat similar to "sorted", isn't it?

If you can have duplicates in the list, use `msort`:

```
sorted(L) :- msort(L, L).
```

If you do not allow duplicates, use `sort`:

```
sorted_uniq(L) :- sort(L, L).
```

Neither leaves behind choice points.

This leaves you with the choice point left by the solution in the other answer. You can make a list and then fill it up.

```
generate_list(N, Z, L) :-
    length(L, N),
    generate_list_1(L, Z, 0).

generate_list_1([], _, _).
generate_list_1([X|Xs], Z, X) :-
    X1 is X^2 + Z,
    X1 >= X, % Checks for order!
    generate_list_1(Xs, Z, X1).
```

This implementation only gives you increasing lists and does not leave behind unnecessary choice points.

Answer (score 1):

To extend the previous answers, in particular the one from Willem Van Onsem, you can write something like:

```
my_ord(P,L):- 
    call(P,L),
    ordered(L).
```

And then you can query `?- my_ord(generate_list(5, 1),L).`
To remove choice points, you can use `once/1` on both `call/2` and `ordered/1` or write another predicate like `my_ord_(P,L):- once(my_ord(P,L))` or place the cut `!`. 
Considering Willem Van Onsem answer, you need to add a cut after `generate_list(0, _, _, [])`. In your ordered/1 you need a cut after `ordered([])` and  `ordered([_])`.